# Where Servlet exceptions are logged to in standalone Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, stdout, stderr, exception-logging

I download Tomcat zip distribution.  Unzip it and configure it using the setenv.bat script as advised.  The content of the setenv.bat is as follows:

```
@echo off
set CATALINA_HOME=D:\tomcat7_inst_8543\tomcat7062
set CATALINA_BASE=D:\tomcat7_inst_8543\tomcat7062
set JAVA_HOME=D:\tomcat7_inst_8543\jdk17051
set JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

I deploy an war application by copying the war file under the webapps directory.  Start up the Tomcat server.  The war application executes as expected.  However, I cannot find the tomcat7-stderr.log and the tomcat7-stdout.log when exceptions occur inside the war application.

(If the Tomcat Windows Service distribution is installed and the same war is deployed on it, the tomcat7-stderr.log and the tomcat7-stdout.log appear in the tomcat/logs directory.)

I don't know why the tomcat7-stderr.log and the tomcat7-stdout.log are not created in standalone Tomcat server as described above.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the bruteforce aproach and just search for *.log and either filter for just the last day, or just sort for created date?

Comment: I did that.  These files were not found.  Looks they are not created.  But, I just found that the exception information are written to the logs\localhost.{date}.log file.  Still don't know why?